# Process sessions foreach minute

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table that stores sessions. The columns are: `ID`, `Start` (Timestamp) and `Stop` (Timestamp, can be NULL).

It's for online radio. A listener connects to the stream, and a row is created. Once they stop listening, Stop is updated to the current time.

Currently, it's about 80K rows per day.

I'd like to process the sessions once a day by determining the max amount of listeners for each minute, and push that data into a different table: `Timestamp`, `ListenerCount` (`UNSIGNED SMALL INT`).

I'm not super concerned with speed, just with working out how I can process this data within MySQL. I'm assuming I use a stored procedure (not much experience there), loop over each minute between the `MIN(Start)` and `Max(Stop)`, and do a `COUNT()` between `x-minute` and `x-minute:59`.

Does this sound viable? Is there a better way?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea you could build on to achieve this: create a simple table that contains only a list of integers from 1 to `24*60` (i.e. number of minutes in a day). Use this to generate the list of minutes in the day you're interested in. Then join that on your session data, grouping by "minute" to get a count of active sessions.

Probably better explained with an example:

#### Tables:

```
-- Holds a list of integers
create table minutes (m int) engine innodb;
-- The session data
create table sessions (id int,
                       st timestamp,
                       en timestamp) engine innodb;
```

#### Generate the list of "minutes"

```
delimiter ;;
create procedure fill_minutes()
begin
  declare i int default 0;
  while i < 60*24 do
    insert into minutes(m) values (i);
    set i = i + 1;
  end while;
end;;
delimiter ;

start transaction;
call fill_minutes();
commit;
```

<sub>Adapted from [Generating a range of numbers in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)</sub>

To generate the minutes in a given day:

```
select
    date('2013-01-01 00:00:00') + interval m minute
from
    minutes;
```

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00
2013-01-01 00:01:00
2013-01-01 00:02:00
2013-01-01 00:03:00
2013-01-01 00:04:00
2013-01-01 00:05:00
....
```

A bit of fake data:

```
insert into sessions (id, st, en)
values (1, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '2013-01-01 00:10:00')
,      (2, '2013-01-01 00:05:00', '2013-01-01 00:10:00')
,      (3, '2013-01-01 00:07:00', '2013-01-01 00:12:00');
```

#### Join the minute table with the session data

```
select
    dates.d, count(*)
from
    (select date('2013-01-01 00:00:00') + interval m minute d from minutes) dates
    join sessions s on ((dates.d >= s.st) and (dates.d < s.en))
group by dates.d
order by dates.d;
```

```
d                   count(*)
2013-01-01 00:00:00 1
2013-01-01 00:01:00 1
2013-01-01 00:02:00 1
2013-01-01 00:03:00 1
2013-01-01 00:04:00 1
2013-01-01 00:05:00 2
2013-01-01 00:06:00 2
2013-01-01 00:07:00 3
2013-01-01 00:08:00 3
2013-01-01 00:09:00 3
2013-01-01 00:10:00 1
2013-01-01 00:11:00 1
```

Note:

- I don't know how to avoid that "list of minutes" table in MySQL. Doable in Oracle with a `select ... from dual connect by level <= ...` or similar.
- You'll probably need to restrict the join on `sessions` more to avoid a full scan of that table (limiting the start date at least, start and end sounds better)